# Help remembering name of boot CD (maybe it wasn't a live CD)

Tags: linux, ntfs, livecd

I am struggling to remember the name of a boot CD I have since lost the disc for. It was great for cloning discs, and resetting passwords.

It's NOT the UBCD4Win, and it defos wasn't Knoppix.

I have checked the LiveCD list and can't seem to find it there by doing a 'sort by'.

I seem to remember it was called something like GS Tools but that might be more or less completely wrong. It had an unusual but memorable name.

Makes me wonder how I came across it in the first place!

Comment: Hiren's boot cd?

Comment: Yep, that was it!  xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one I can think of is [Hiren's boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) It contains several cloning and password resetting tools and a Linux and Mini Windows XP bootable. It's the only one I use.

Comment: That was it! Well done! Why is that so hard to find online! ARG

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Comment: That doesn't look like a boot CD to me

Comment: Download the iso to make a bootable CD.